# How to save/upload selenium screenshots directly to a 3rd party? Discord/Imgur/Other Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to save screenshots from selenium directly to a 3rd party site such as Imgur/discord and etc.
I know how to save the image to desktop or a directory on the localhost, but I was wondering if it is possible to upload it to a third party as mentioned before without the need for the file to saved onto the localhost.

Comment: If the 3rd party, supports parse of links to the upload 'window', you can directly send it to the input element which handles the upload.

Comment: @Infern0 do you know of any 3rd parties that do? I'm fairly new to this and if you know any it would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: any site that allows an upload should have a form or even an API that you can use.  There's a bunch of posts here on uploading files... see this for instance:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44800737/failing-to-upload-a-file-using-selenium